# how to fix this R console "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large"?

Tags: r, plot

I am running model based clustering and I don't know to fix this error.

```
plot(df_optimal_mc, what = 'uncertainty')
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I already try the `graphics.off()` or `par(mfcol=c(5,3),mai=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0))` and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the margins of the plot using the par() function. Try using the following code:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1)

plot(df_optimal_mc, what = 'uncertainty')
```

This should help reduce the margin size and allow you to plot the figure.